# Input type radio - how to use the for attribute for a span and not only for the label

Tags: html, radio-button

I've two radio buttons.
If I click on the radio dot or the label the clicked element is active.

I include two span tags with fontawesome icons and if I click on the span the correct radio button should be active.

I try it with the for attribute but it doesn't work.

Is it possible?

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span class="fa fa-address-book" for="firmenkunde"></span>
            <span class="notepad--display" data-txt="ShopNavigationFirmenkunde">
                <input type="radio" id="firmenkunde" name="kunde" value="firmenkunde">
                <label for="firmenkunde">Firmenkunde</label>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="fa fa-address-book-o" for="privatkunde"></span>
            <span class="notepad--display" data-txt="ShopNavigationPrivatkunde">
                <input type="radio" id="privatkunde" name="kunde" value="privatkunde">
                <label for="privatkunde">Privatkunde</label>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wys7e7p2/

Thank you.

@edit:

I don't want to use javascript.

Comment: The text already activates the respective radio button. Do you want the images to as well?

Comment: Yes. That would be great. I edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your fiddle here in a snippet because the images don't show up. But I'm linking a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wys7e7p2/1/. The `for` attribute doesn't work on `span` tags. So I changed your `span`'s to `label`'s and modified the CSS to keep the design the same.

Comment: Ah okay! This information is perfect. Thanks for that!

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck.

Comment: Oh, just wrap with `label`, no need in `for` and `id` https://jsfiddle.net/pwf8ovch/2/